# asp.net insert the same value according to check box selection

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 drop down with some data, 1 date field and 1 field total
Now i added a check box.
if i insert value for drop down,  1 drop down  2 in that date and if i the check box is checked when i click save the same value should be inserted for every date in the year

Example:
if i select date 1.04.2013

I have:
Drop down 1 is company , drop down  2 is depart, total is 2000 and date is 1.04.2013

For that depart of the company the value 2000 should be inserted for every month in the year if check box is checked.

Comment: Are you saying the value 2000 should show on the page for every month in 2013, or that the value should be stored in a database?

Comment: the value should be saved for every month in database

Comment: OK, can you post your code so we can take a look?